# Regex take text after ":" excluding ":"

Tags: node.js, regex

I have this string:

```
194.44.176.116:8080
```

I want regex to take everything after the colon ':' but not take : itself.  How do I do that?

This is something I did but it grabs numbers and the colon ':' which I don't want.

```
var portRe = /(?<=:)\d{2,5}$/gi;
```

I'm using this in NodeJs application.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?  The answer would likely depend on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex to get everything between the `:` and the end would be:

```
/[^:]+$/
```

But as we know,that the port is a number, you can just check for the number at end of string:

```
/[0-9]+$/
```

Please note that this does not check if there is a `:` and so just returns the last digit. If you are sure that you have a string as you provided, those two are the easiest to understand minimalist solutions.

Otherwise refer to the other answers to do a lookahead/lookbehind or work with non capturing / capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

A general strategy here would be to just use a capture group to isolate what you really want to match:

```
/.*:(\d{2,5})/gi
```

Then access what you have captured in the first capture group.

```js
var myString = "194.44.176.116:8080";
var myRegexp = /.*:(\d{2,5})/gi;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```